# Android MP Chart, Bar Chart Y Axis display from 0.0f

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have following bar chart. I wish to display data from 0.0f - 10.9 in Y Axis. I tried using setLabelCount but it doesnt help. t

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is option of setting maximum and minimum values:

```
barChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinValue(3f);
barChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMaxValue(10f);
```

also:

```
dataset.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
```

because by default graph is dependent on left axis you changed labels range for right axis above and this line will make graph axis dependency w.r.t right axis.

Comment: I tried using your suggested solution earlier, but it didn help.

Comment: I edited my answer sorry buddy that was for iOS I just ran project again on android and tested it will work please check updated answer. Let me know if it works and it will surely work. So happy coding :)

Comment: Also tell me which version of library you are using if it is 3.x.x then above solution is deprecated but it will work bro

Comment: Okay Thank You, I will check and let you know :D

Comment: if it works dont forget to mark is as answer mate :)

Comment: I have solved that label issue with your solution. but the score is mismatching now. I mean to say, my bar score is 10 but label is not matching. I am using version 3.0.2

Comment: can you please share screenshot I will check and solve it for u. Actually i cant understand what u wanted to say

Comment: ok I found solution add this to your code  dataset.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);

Comment: ok bro thankyou if you have any issues regarding this library I am your man mate so whenever you have question regarding this whenever u post question here just tag me the question I will help you with it :)

Comment: Cool, I do need your help, I have to make certain graphs I will post new question and will tag you. Thanks once again bro :D

Comment: I will wait buddy I dont have much work these days so hunting here so I may help someone :p

Comment: I have plenty of work to do. I am working as a intern and new to android as well. I have good experience with Java but for android I started since June this year.

Comment: Ook then best of luck buddy :) happy coding :)

Comment: Please check my new question regarding MPAndoid Chart.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052515/mpandoid-chart-with-following-styling