# MPAndoid Chart with following styling

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid Chart for my project. 
I want to make the styling of LineChart as follows. Basically I want all 4 Quadrants and other styling like gradient colors etc.

[image]

Comment: Also lineChart.getAxis().setDrawGridLines(false); is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make it to fill color behind line by doing this:

```
dataset.setDrawFilled(true);
```

After that you have to give gradient for that you have make an xml file like that in drawables as gradient_chart_color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#FFF300"
    android:endColor="#F5F094" />
    </shape>
```

After that you have to do this :

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_red);
dataset.setFillDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: I did the same, now what remain is how to set position of Y Axis on middle ??

Comment: I think you can place a line but to show axis values I dont think we can do that

Comment: Also how to remove the circles from graph ? I looked into MPAndoid github page, there is example of linechart(cubic lines) I tried it by setting mode to dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER); but this didn helped

Comment: Ok for cubic you have to do this :   dataset.setDrawCubic(true); you can set true false according to ur conditions mate

Comment: If it works dont mforget to mark my post as answer buddy :)

Comment: setDrawCubic is deprecated i guess, and i tried dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER) but no help

Comment: Ok I used old version in android for new version I dont know the exact sytax But I used new one for iOS swift

Comment: LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER = true Try such I never tried this but try this

Comment: or try LineDataSet.Mode = .CUBIC_Bezier... Idid in iOS in that way

Comment: Okay somewhat it is working now the last thing is, how to remove the lines? I only want points ?

Comment: which lines, line of your data if yes set line color to transparent will do the trick ;)

Comment: Your welcome buddy let me know if you have any problem again. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have posted new Question, please check if you can help. Also I have posted another question besides MPAndroid library. Thank You !

Comment: Can you please give me link to another question buddy ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090070/how-to-increase-size-of-radar-chart-mpandoid-chart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072425/android-heatmap-on-canvas-or-imageview

Comment: To clarify, were you able to fill the chart with multiple different colors/patterns? i.e. from x=0 to x=5 have red fill for example, then x=5 to x=10 have blue fill? I see the dataset.setDrawFilled(true) tip but is there a way to specify horizontal ranges for a certain fill color?