# Android Heatmap on canvas or ImageView

Tags: android, canvas, heatmap

I want to generate dynamic heatmap just as below on either canvas or imageview. 
I looked into google map heat map API, but I can't get the expected output. 
 [image]

Comment: I never worked on such thing but lets find a way for that mate.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I found a  project on github, but that is implemented using opengl, and very hard to understand.

Comment: have you look into this https://github.com/HeartlandSoftware/AndroidHeatMap

Comment: This looks very simple and easy to work with, easy methods to call and pass data.

Comment: This might work, Thanks alot :D

Comment: Radar chart issue is yours too ? I proposed a way there a little hack dont know if that works but give that a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should go with that

github.com/HeartlandSoftware/AndroidHeatMap

Comment: If it works do let me know and yes I need reputation :D

Comment: i got that bro :-p

Comment: how did you do it in an image?