# How to Increase size of Radar Chart MPAndoid Chart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to increase size of MPAndroid Radar Chart. I observed that the size increases gradually when i increase size of the chart itself, but I want the area to be same just Chart size should be increased. 
[image]

After adding following code:

```
mChart.setScaleY(1.2f);
mChart.setScaleX(1.2f);
```

it is getting displaced

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use a little hack to do that.I never worked on radar chart but if it supports zoom then we may zoom it when we create it to fit to our requirements. Again you have to test it I am not sure if it will work. Its just an idea. If you did that in my purposed way please do let me know.

**Zooming (programmatically)**

zoomIn(): Zooms in by 1.4f, into the charts center.

zoomOut(): Zooms out by 0.7f, from the charts center.

zoom(float scaleX, float scaleY, float x, float y): Zooms in or out by the given scale factor. x and y are the coordinates (in pixels) of the zoom center. Remember that a scale of 1f = no zoom.

zoom(float scaleX, float scaleY, float xValue, float yValue, AxisDependency axis): Zooms in or out by the given scale factor. xValue and yValue are the actual data values (not pixels) of the zoom center. Remember that a scale of 1f = no zoom.

Comment: Okay I will try and let you know bro. But if i zoom, would it just zoom the inner triangle or the whole chart ?

Comment: Hey, i tried but it doesnt help. also I have new question, please look into it.

Comment: hello akash can you please share link of your question buddy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177157/mpandroid-line-chart-single-data-point-with-curve

Comment: why u are setting scale along x and y because it means that you are giving it new reference point to draw instead of default which is zero

Comment: Then How should i zoom it ? setScaleX and setScaleY helped me in zooming the view, but on small screens i am facing this displacement issue.

Comment: buddy for zooming use zoom method look into docs for specific method which suits your case

Comment: Okay, I thought there is specific method related to radar chart. I will look into it Thanks.